# GTM tag wont fire upon button click - Limited options

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, pixel

I'm trying to get a "complete appointment" button to fire in GTM when someone clicks on it, but it's not consistent. The options to make it fire are limited as well (at least it seems so to me). I've tried click class but the script for it is vague and can apply to any other button. Same thing for Click ID. I can't tag the thank you page either bc it's on a subdomain we're not tracking (the site is tangled with subdomains). I was thinking maybe doing something with value=complete appt similar to click text but not sure how to go about it.

Script below:

````
```javascript
<div class="forms-action-button-container">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary 
submit-forms-nopay" data-loading-text="Confirming Appointment..." 
value="Complete Appointment »" data-qa="submit-button" data- 
original-text="Complete Appointment »">
    </div>
```
````

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: ty for the heads up!

Comment: add a screenshot of your GTM trigger config.

Answer (score 0):

In your trigger logic, use Clicked Element -> Matching CSS Selector -> [original-text="Complete Appointment »"]

or something similar to that. CSS Selectors are a lot more powerful than just classes and ids.